# Replace a URL parameter using JQuery Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, url

i have a url that has several parameters, and i want to replace them using JQuery (not javascript).

```
var str = "http://example.com/index.php?color=red&size=large&quantity=5";
var newQty = 10;
```

How can i change the quantity using JQuery ONLY if quantity exists as a parameter? How can i change a parameter that isn't at the end of the query string, such as size=large?

I prefer to use regex and .replace function, if anyone can help me with the proper code please... something like this.

`var newStr = str.replace(REGEX, "quantity="+newQty);`

Comment: do some searching...there are lots of posts here and small url scripts and libraries on web. Start here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
var REGEX = /quantity\=[0-9]+/;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.